# micro sd card help

Tags: 12.04, sd-card

I am running a fresh (full wipe install) of ubuntu 12.04 and I am trying to get my microsd card to work. The card is a samsung 2gb microsd card, and the reader I am using is a usb dongle (targus multi card reader, has been used once on the same computer when I was previously running windows)
The microsd card is inserted into a sandisk microsd to SD adapter.

the reader shows up under `lsusb` as:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 058f:6366 Alcor Micro Corp. Multi Flash Reader
```

I have inserted the dongle and it does recognize the card reader under disk utility. It reads my cd drive, hard drive, and my "multiple card reader" and it reads the storage space as 2gb. However it says it is not partitioned?
If I use the disk utility to attempt to format the volume (not the drive, as it seems to be referring to the card reader itself), it fails and says the following
an error occurred while performing an operation on "2.0gb unrecognized" (whole-disk volume on multiple card reader): the operation failed
with the following details:

```
Error creating file system: helper exited with exit code 1: Error calling fsync(2) on /dev/sdb: Input/output error
```

To be honest I don't care if I get the card working. All I need to do is get the sd card as bootable for a project (trying to root my friend's nook tablet).

Suggestions? I would prefer to try fighting with this before going and trying to purchase a new card reader.

Comment: What type of bootable-ness does the SD card need?  Do you have an image (e.g. ISO)?  Are you trying to load Raspbian?

Comment: just edited main post, basically just trying to root my friend's nook tablet. I have an image file for the custom recovery (clockwork mod) just need to make the sd card bootable to boot from it, then I can do the rest un-tethered.

Answer (score 0):

You need to unmount the card via Disk Utility, then **format each partition on the card to create one partition**, then format the card itself and create a new partition to your liking.

Some people struggle with Disk Utility logic in which case you could use Windows to format as usual and then plug it back into your Ubuntu machine.

Comment: it actually doesn't even allow me to unmount the disk, I have the option for safe removal of the drive but that just makes it disappear. Now it won't even show the drive when i unplug and reinsert.

Comment: Then use GParted to format and partition it.

Comment: Gparted won't recognize anything other than my computers hard drive

Comment: @daltonator9690 Are you certain? In the top right hand corner is s drop down option which you need to click on to select which storage device to work on, it would default to your internal hdd so you would need to select that and then choose the SD Card.

Comment: I am certain. Clicking the menu you refer to yields only my computers hard drive as an option.